# loading a os from network with a USB stick

Tags: linux, usb

I have my favorite OS (Linux Mint) completely confgured the way i like it. It took me 3 days because i need to customize a lot of things. I currently run it off a USB stick but it performs sub-optimal.

I would like to know if the following thing can be done:

- Have a linux image on a network drive (cloud storage, S3 or something)
- Have a USB drive load the image into memory
- Run the OS completely in memory and cache the data locally on the USB drive

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NetbootCD](http://netbootcd.tuxfamily.org/), which, despite its name is also provided in a convenient hybrid iso image suitable for a USB stick.

It is programmed to download installable versions of several different OSes from the Net, in the `nbscript.sh`, but that can be easily modified to download your own version wherever it is stored.

Comment: i have no idea where to get started with this, for example how to make an image from my current setup. I think this thing would only work if it somehow syncs to my image in the cloud. But i don't know if a thing like that is even possible.